# Rails 7 - Multiple series charts using Chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I am new to Ruby on Rails development, and I am working on building charts is a Ruby on Rails application using `Chartkick` gem.

I am taking values from a form and storing the param values directly in the instance variables. I am then using those instance variables to plot graph.

I have three instance variables. Two of them (@usl and @lsl) contain integer values and @h contains a hash.

Below is the code I am running to plot the graph.

```
<%= line_chart([{name: "PROCESS_TIME_SAMPLES", data: @h.map{|t| [t.index, t] }}, {name: "USL", data: @usl},{name: "LSL", data: @lsl}]) %>
```

However, I can see that @usl and @lsl are not getting plotted in the graph. Only @h is getting plotted successfully as below.

[image]

Comment: Not sure how any of this is working because you said `@h` is a `Hash` but your iteration uses `[t.index,t]` this would result in `[Enumerator, Array]` and I am uncertain how chart kick is turning this into graphable data. Chartkick appears to be looking for data to be in the format of `{x => y}` but I am sure that `[[x,y]]` probably also works, so maybe try `[{name: "PROCESS_TIME_SAMPLES", data: @h}, {name: "USL", data: @usl.zip(@usl)},{name: "LSL", data: @lsl.zip(@lsl)}]` ?

Comment: @engineersmnky Hi! Thank you for your response. I tried the code snippet shared by you, but it shows an error. `undefined method zip for 15:Integer`. @lsl and @usl contains integer values.

Comment: So you just want straight lines on the graph? If so then maybe `[{name: "PROCESS_TIME_SAMPLES", data: @h},{name: "USL", data: @h.map {|k,_| [k,@usl]}},{name: "LSL", data: @h.map {|k,_| [k,@lsl]}}]`

Comment: Hi @engineersmnky thank you for your response and for sharing the details. Your inputs helped me in understanding how chartkick works. I wanted all 3 instance variables (@lsl, @usl and @h) to be plotted on the graph. @h was already a hash but since @lsl and @usl were integers, I converted then to array using ```Array.wrap``` and then converted that array to a hash. This was I was able to plot all the variables.